# disable particular rows in custom picker

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uipickerview

im developing an application which shows picker with the following values:
1.Morning
2.Noon
3.Evening

Based on the current time i need to show the respective values.

say if its 3PM the use should be able to select only Evening.

Now my questions is, is there any way i could make the "morning and Noon" unselectable. similar to Date picker can i grey out the options?? the  user should be aware of all the options but he should be able to select option based on time.

thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you just display an alert view when user finishes selecting the value, and animate the picker back to its original value.

Comment: And why do you need to give all that options to the user if he is able to select only one among them? It's quite strange.

Comment: sara and ankit , this is my requirement. it should be available but not selectable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to grey out some values in picker view, then make use of the following delegate API to override the view for that position.

```
 - (UIView *)viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Create a UILabel and make its text color to grey and return it as view for the above one.

And if the grey text is selected, animate to the default selection by calling the below API.

```
 - (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: in this method -- (UIView *)viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)componen; if i create a label with grey color wont all rows be grey??? i want few rows in grey (which are non selectable) and few in black(selectable rows )

Comment: Ok. Since you get both component(NSInteger) and row(NSInteger) value, you can gray out the non-selectable items and black out the remaining based upon these values.

Answer (score 0):

To gray out rows in a Picker, there is a much easier solution than creating your own View. That is to use attributedTitleForRow.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString?
```

Because this function will fall back to titleForRow if you return nil, you can return gray for the disabled rows, and use the standard titleForRow to return the rest. As an example :

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    // Need to provide the below function isRowDisabled that returns true as needed
    if isRowDisabled(row:row) {
        let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]
        let str = NSAttributedString(string: "my gray text on row \(row)", attributes:attributes)
        return str
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return "my normal text on row \(row)"
}
```

You'll have to then ignore the didSelectRow for the disabled rows as mentioned in the other replies.